# MySQL UPDATE query styntax error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a year column in MySQL with the following query:

```
UPDATE PUB.oa_inthed
SET PUB.oa_inthed.yearno ='2016'
WHERE PUB.oa_intnom.intid = 'XC352332'
```

but keep receiving this error:

> [AnyDAC][Phys][ODBC][DirectData][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about ".oa_inthes.yearno ='2016' WHERE PUB.oa" (10713)

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the error says "inthes", yet your sample query has "inthed"?

Comment: Does your query end with a semi-colon or is yearno reserved ? See this :http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000032174  and this http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P11495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `oa_inthed` is the table name then just specify it once and again table name in `WHERE` doesn't match as of `UPDATE` statement. Your query should look like

```
UPDATE PUB.oa_inthed
SET yearno ='2016'
WHERE PUB.oa_intnom.intid = 'XC352332'
           ^........... This should be oa_inthed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem

```
UPDATE PUB.oa_inthed
SET PUB.oa_inthed.yearno ='2016'
WHERE PUB.oa_inthed.intid = 'XC352332'


oa_intnom = oa_inthed
```

in where clause..